# GSCRIPT - How to cache HTML page content?

Tags: caching, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm kinda stuck with something here.

I've a HTML template that i'm loading, and within this page there's a lot of JavaScript going on.

I'm trying to accelerate the operation by caching the template with the `onOpen()` of my Google Sheet. I can't figure how to cache my HTML page `CalForm.html` (from my internal Google Sheet scripts).

Here's what I have for now:

### Creating the cache

```
function CacheCreate() {

CacheService.getScriptCache().put('CalCache', 'CalForm');
 Browser.msgBox("done");
}
```

### Get the cache

```
var evalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Evaluation');
  var row = evalSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();

  var CalCache2 = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('CalCache');

  Browser.msgBox(CacheService.getScriptCache().get('CalCache'))

  initialize(row);

  //var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  //var cache2 = cache.get('rss-feed-contents');

  //Browser.msgBox(cache.get('rss-feed-contents'));

var html = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile(CalCache2)
      .evaluate()
      .setWidth(1200)
      .setHeight(560)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Calculatrice');
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to get the HTML from your "internal Google Sheet scripts", the following code will get the HTML (in string format), given that you have a File in your Script called "template.html".

```
var template = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('template').getContent();
```

I run a check to see if the data is already in the cache...

```
function getObjectsFromCache(key, objects, flush) 
{
  Logger.log("Running:  getObjectsFromCache(" + key + ", objects)");
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  var cached = cache.get(key);
  flush = false;  // 1st run 45.33, 2nd run 46.475
  //flush = true;// 65.818 seconds
  if (cached != null && flush != true) 
  {
    Logger.log("\tEXISTING DATA -> ");
    cached = cache.get(key);
  }
  else
  {
    Logger.log("\tNEW DATA -> ");
    //Logger.log("\tJSON.stringify(objects):  " + JSON.stringify(objects) + ", length:  " + objects.length);
    //If you're working with spreadsheet objects, or array data, you'll want to put the data in the cache as a string, and then reformat the data to it's original format, when it is returned.
    //cache.put(key, JSON.stringify(objects), 1500); // cache for 25 minutes
    //In your case, the HTML does not need to be stringified.
    cache.put(key, objects, 1500); // cache for 25 minutes
    cached = objects;
  }
  return cached;
}
```

I commented-out the JSON.Stringify(objects), because in my original code I use another function called formatCachedData(cache, key) to return the different types of data - a multi-dimensional array (spreadsheet data), or Google user data from AdminDirectory.Users.list({...}).